# Can't get neither CKEditor nor WYSIGYG Module to work!

Tags: wysiwyg

I have the Drupal 7.21 installation and I am using a downloaded theme (premium responsive). I am trying to install an editor for my website entries but I have not been able to get it to work. This is the information on the two I have tried:

CKEditor version 4.0.2 and CKEditor Module 7.x-1.12
OR
WYSIWYG Module version 7.x-2.2 with TinyMCE 3.5.8

I have carefully checked the installation instructions for all and they are correctly installed. I have been able to enable both (not at the same time, obviously) without any errors. However, when I try to add content I don't see the toolbars, only the plain white box.

So far it has been very frustrating. I have checked every thread that describes similar problems and tried every suggestion but it just won't work.

Can anyone provide a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to /admin/config/content/formats and make sure you have a text format for the role(s) you are working with.
2. Go to /admin/config/content/wysiwyg and make sure you have added buttons to the editor (click on "Edit" and then under Buttons & Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had checked both suggestions above, and just for completeness I checked again and everything is set correctly.

Comment: Ok. With TinyMCE the cache needs to be cleaned 100% first to see the changes. Please make sure you go to admin/config/development/performance and clean your cache. I would also clean your browser's cache. @Miguel

Comment: That was it!!!!! Once the cache was cleared I can see the editor.